# Problems with multithreading when Qt app uses libraries that use multithreading

Tags: multithreading, macos, qt

I'm using Qt 5.12.3 (Clang 10.0 (Apple), 64 bit) on MacOS 10.14.6 to build an app on a MacBook pro 15 mid 2018 2.2ghz i7.

Basically, the app calls a library I'm using that processes video frames (processFrame, below), one frame at a time. processFrame launches two main threads that receive callbacks at non-deterministic intervals, based on calculations it makes on incoming frames.

If I call processFrame and feed it video frames without Qt, it works perfectly fine every time, i.e. when the code looks like this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    //QApplication a(argc, argv);
    //MainWindow w;

    while(frame) {
        frame = getVideoFrame("video.mp4");
        processFrame(frame);
    }


    //w.show();
    //return a.exec();
}
```

However, if I uncomment the Qt inits, but don't run the Qt window process itself, i.e:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;

    while(frame) {
        frame = getVideoFrame("video.mp4");
        processFrame(frame);
    }


    //w.show();
    //return a.exec();
}
```

I get problems with race conditions and thread management. These problems become particularly bad when I run intensive, unrelated background processes on my machine.

In testing, it seems like Qt might be stopping threads in processFrame from running on a core, somewhat arbitrarily, as it decides to allocate processing resources.

Again, I need to stress that I cannot get these race conditions *at all*, provided I run processFrame without Qt.

Is there a way to prevent Qt from managing processing resources in external libraries (if that's the problem)?

Comment: Is it the declaration of `MainWindow` that causes things to break, or is declaring only the `QApplication` object enough to break things?

Comment: You say `"I get problems with race conditions and thread management."` -- can you be specific?  How do these problems manifest themselves?  I suspect you may be misdiagnosing the real problem.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner great question -- unfortunately I lost the test case that I could use to test that, it would take 1hour+ to recreate, and our team has decided to lock things down on the library side and not worry about how Qt handles things. So the short answer is I don't know...

Comment: @G.M. good question, the issue as best I can tell is that Qt pauses threads at its discretion, which means that other processes do not have what they need on time. I was hoping there was an easy way to turn off thread management in Qt to get a short-term workaround, but instead our team has decided to take the longer (and only real) road to robustness and ensure the threads in the library account for their own race issues, regardless of what system happens to be calling it. cheers!

Comment: Why don't you run `a.exec()`? Or you actually do?